# Efeito do "href=.section" no botão, para levar o usuário ao trecho do site

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Em um site que estou desenvolvendo, criei tudo em uma mesma index, uma página de apresentação do trabalho apenas, mas, utilizei o href nos botões e setei os sections, quando o usuário clica, leva até as sections do site.
Problemática: Está funcionando, mas, estou querendo que no momento em que clico no botão, tenha um efeito slow-motion até chegar na section, é possível?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar javascript para fazer essa animação que você quer, segue um exemplo:

```js
$('.links a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href'),
  targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;

  $('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: targetOffset - 70
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sobre">SOBRE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clientes">CLIENTES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
  </ul>                         
</nav>
```

```js
$('.links a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href'),
  targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;

  $('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: targetOffset - 70
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<nav class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sobre">SOBRE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#servicos">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contato">CONTATO</a></li>
  </ul>                         
</nav>

<section id="home">
  ...
</section>

<section id="sobre">
  ...
</section>

<section id="servicos">
  ...
</section>

<section id="contato">
  ...
</section>
```